# Custom font on canvas only working for safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm currently building a canvas game in JavaScript and jQuery. For the statusbar I wanted to use a custom font, named "pixelart.ttf". In index.html I added the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: pixelart;
        src: url(misc/pixelart.ttf);
    }
</style>
```

It is before *all* scripts are loaded. The canvas is also on this page.

This is the code that should draw the statusbar with the font:

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.1)';
context.textBaseline = 'top';
context.font = fontSize + ' ' + fontName; // will become '25px pixelart'
context.fillText(currentText, 50, 50);
```

In Safari on both Mac and iPhone the font works, on all other browsers it does not.
When I look at the loaded resources in Chrome or Firefox the font is there, but it shows another default font.

I tried some things. For example adding this at the top of the body:

```
<div style"font-family: pixelart"></div>
```

But this also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It wasn't a loading problem, I checked on that. I found the solution, but thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `.ttf` you need to have your font in `.eot` `.woff2` `.woff` to make it work.

css example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourFONT';
    src: url(/yourFont.eot');
    src: url('/yourFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/yourFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/yourFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/yourFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/yourFont.svg#yourFONT') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Why is that? With plain CSS/HTML it works with only `.ttf` on all browsers (except IE of course). Is it different for `canvas`?

Comment: @JeroenJK: to get cross-browser compatibility you should use css for the embedded fonts. In addition to this make sure your JS run after body loads.

Comment: Thank you. Converting it to all those types and including it fixed the problem!